# How to enable the scheduler in DNN7

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-settings

My hosting provider had to disable the scheduler on my DNN 7.1 site, because it was taking up too much server resources.

I've since disabled the "Search: Site Crawler" scheduled event, and I would like to now re-enable the scheduler.

I've navigated to the Host/Schedule page, and I can see the button "View Schedule Status". I click this button and I get the message "Scheduling is currently disabled".

There are two buttons, start and stop. When I hover over both my cursor changes to a "circular x not working", and clicking the two buttons does nothing.

Any tips on how to re-enable the scheduler? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the Scheduler Mode in Host Settings set to Disabled:

[image: DNN Host Settings]

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this directly through the database if you need.

The command to update the host settings for the Scheduler are:

```
update HostSettings 
set SettingValue = 0
where SettingName = 'SchedulerMode'
```

Where setting value '0' = Disabled, 1 = Timer Method, 2 = Request Method.

If doing a direct database update it is best to restart the app to clear the cache and pick up the new value.  This can be done by 'touching' the web.config file.

This type of approach is important if you have a situation where a scheduled task issue is preventing the site from running properly and you can't load the UI.